# Is there a difference in how the sed -e string is quoted?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Whenever I have seen sed examples using -e the command string has usually been delimited by  single, not double, quotes like this:

```
sed -e ' <command>' <input>
sed -e 's/CSV/csv/g' csv-instructions
```

Are there differences between using double and single quotes, and, if so, what are they?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is actually not about sed.

Quoting is a *shell* issue, and therefore depends on the shell you are using.

For example in *bash*, double quote allow the interpretation of special characters such as $ (variable expansion) or * (wildcard), whereas single quotes don't.

You can consult this page for a thorough explanation on the topic:

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html

[And you will likely will find other related posts on SO with more appropriate keywords :-) ]

Comment: Thanks. Your answer has jogged my memory from a long time ago. You've just explained why sometimes I see different behavior when sed commands are in a .sed file instead of in a -e command line.

Comment: Quoting is a shell *issue*, not a shell *problem*.